# In objective c, when creating objects, why do we need to use *?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In objective c, when creating objects, why do we need to use *? For example, we are creating

```
NSString *string =@"i ma string";
```

In the above code why do we need to use *string

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not read a C tutorial before going to Objective-C? This is trivial.

Comment: Hi rar, i am new objective c, what are the important topics i need to cover in C language for learning objective C?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*` means that it is pointer to object, not the actual object

Comment: what is the difference between heap memory and stack memory in objective C, AlieN can please explain if it is possible

Comment: @Siva http://gribblelab.org/CBootcamp/7_Memory_Stack_vs_Heap.html

Answer (score 0):

Objective-C mandates that you access objects via pointers, such that they're created on the heap and never on the stack